@Query sql in JpaRepository thread safe?
Hello i am new to java language and i have to create method that will

Update what value, how are you updating (retrieving, +1 in memory and storing or are you using the databsae). Why wouldn't you be able to use locking on the DB level? You have a database so use it.

Create triggers in the database to handle value increments after insert or update.
Triggers are thread-safe and can manage increments without additional configuration.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
